# Not able to change the ID of dropdown list after cloning

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function to clone the details of a room and append based on the number of room selected. After cloning I'm changing the ID of each element present in that room. I'm able to change the ID of two drop down list and one label successfully. But I'm not able to change the ID of another dropdown list. Please help me here. I'm not able to find any solution for this.

[image]

Please find the pic added. In this pic I'm not able to change the ID of Child age box alone.

```
    function dynamicRoom(rooms) {
    var i = parseInt($('div[id^="room"]:last').prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10);

    for (i; i < rooms; i++) {
        var $div_room = $('div[id^="room"]:last');
        var num_room = parseInt($div_room.prop("id").match(/\d+/g), 10) + 1;
        var x = num_room - 1;
        var $klon_room = $div_room.clone().prop('id', 'room' + num_room);
        $klon_room.find('#ddlAdults' + x).attr("id", "ddlAdults" + num_room);
        $klon_room.find('#ddlChild' + x).attr("id", "ddlChild" + num_room);
        $klon_room.find('#childAgeCollapse' + x + 1).hide();
        $klon_room.find('#childAgeCollapse' + x + 1).attr("id", "childAgeCollapse" + num_room + 1);

        $klon_room.find('#ddlchildAge' + x + 1).attr('id', 'ddlchildAge' + num_room + '1'); //THIS is WHERE I FOUND ISSUEs

        $klon_room.find('#childAge' + x + 1).prop("id", "childAge" + num_room + 1);

        $klon_room.find('#labelRoom' + x).attr("id", "labelRoom" + num_room);
        $klon_room.find("div.childAgeClass" + x).detach();
        $klon_room.find('#labelRoom' + num_room).text('Room ' + num_room);
        $("#Clone").append($klon_room);
    }

}
```

Comment: Should it be `'#ddlchildAge' + x + 1` instead `'#ddlchildAge11'`???

Comment: Also next time please click the `<>` button and add a [mcve]

Comment: Lastly: `var i = $('div[id^="room"]').length`

Comment: yes, you are right Satpal, Its actually #ddlchildAge' + x + 1.
I changed it during my test, even after keeping  #ddlchildAge' + x + 1., ID is not changing.

Comment: Here #ddlAdults and #ddlChild are also dropdown list, there I'm able to change the ID successfully, but only problem is with third dropdwon list.'#ddlchildAge

Answer (score 1):

The error was because of a extra space in id of the dropdown list. After removing that space everything went fine.